# Ruby Grammar

Tags: ruby, grammar, bnf

I'm looking for Ruby grammar in BNF form. Is there an **official** version?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is one [Ruby BNF syntax](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~regan/cse305/RubyBNF.pdf) by the University of buffalo.

Edit: I've also found this alternate [Ruby BNF syntax](https://web.archive.org/web/20150106021034/http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/yacc.html).

Comment: But I don't think the first link is to an "official" grammar.  I hear that the closest thing to an official grammar for Ruby is the parse.y file.

Comment: Unfortunately, the similar UoB and the njit grammars are completely wrong.  There is no do in a for loop, extend and include statements are missing and exception variables are missing.

Answer (score 38):

The YACC syntax is in the Ruby source.  Download it and run the bundled utiliy to get the readable syntax.

```
wget ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p195.tar.gz
tar xvzf ruby-2.0.0-p195.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.0.0-p195
ruby sample/exyacc.rb < parse.y
```

Output sample (total 918 lines for the v2.0.0-p195)

```
program         : top_compstmt
                ;

top_compstmt    : top_stmts opt_terms
                ;

top_stmts       : none
                | top_stmt
                | top_stmts terms top_stmt
                | error top_stmt
                ;

top_stmt        : stmt
                | keyword_BEGIN
                  '{' top_compstmt '}'
                ;

bodystmt        : compstmt
                  opt_rescue
                  opt_else
                  opt_ensure
                ;

compstmt        : stmts opt_terms
                ;
```

Comment: now just `git clone https://github.com/ruby/ruby ; cd ruby ; ruby sample/exyacc.rb < parse.y`

Answer (score 5):

also an official version: Ruby Draft Specification. you can find the grammar there.

Ruby Draft Specification: http://ruby-std.netlab.jp. the server is down, but you can download it from
http://www.ipa.go.jp/osc/english/ruby

Comment: Link is not accessible without a password.

Comment: thanks for the report. The old link worked when I posted that comment. but I've add a new link. It should work now.

Comment: Very cool.I see that its for 1.8.7. Is there a newer one for Ruby 2.0?