# Where to find formal grammar for Ruby on Rails, Cobal, and VSL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compiler-construction, nlp, grammar, formal-languages

Does anyone know where I can get the formal grammar for these languages especially Ruby on Rails?
I'm interested in looking at how the language is processed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby on Rails is a framework, not a language. It's written in the Ruby language. You can get the source for Ruby at http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/. It uses lex and yacc for parsing; as far as I know, that code's contained in parse.y.

Comment: I wasnt able to download the source code from that link, the link on the other page turned out dead but going off what you said that Rails is just a framework i did find the BNF for Ruby.
Here's the link for anyone else that may be interested:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663027/ruby-grammar