# Multiline conditionals in Ruby and other mysteries -- why won't this compile?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby, but I'm having trouble predicting what Ruby will behave under certain circumstances.  For example, the following causes a syntax error:

```
[2, 3, 4].any? do |x|
    (x > 1 
    and x < 4)
end
```

but this compiles fine:

```
[2, 3, 4].any? do |x|
    (x > 1 and 
    x < 4)
end
```

(the difference is in the placement of the *and*)

Why does the former fail to compile, while the latter succeeds, and how would I have known that?  i.e.: since the above seems totally unintuitive, where is the formal grammar for Ruby, like https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html , or a guide like this https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html so I don't have to just *guess* at Ruby's behavior and figure it out by trial & error?

Comment: I can't answer your question on the whitespace/return issue this is causing, I can say that idiomatic ruby prohibits `and, or, not` from conditionals in favor of `&&, ||, !!`.  Maybe look at the Ruby style guides [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) for help with syntax stuff.

Comment: [Ruby does does not really have a formal grammar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663027/ruby-grammar). [parse.y](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y) from the ruby source is as close as it gets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to end the line with an operator if you want the statement to be continued on the next line.

I will try to see if I can re-find the doc on this.

This is documented in the following book , chapter 2.

The Ruby Programming Language
 By David Flanagan, Yukihiro Matsumoto

To paraphrase :
With having semicolons as explicit end of statement indicators, the ruby interpreter must figure out when a statement ends.  It does this by figuring out if a statement is complete or not, if not it continues parsing on the next line.  So

```
total = x +
 y
```

is the same as total = x + Y since total = x + is not a complete statement

but

```
total = x
+y
```

is the same as total = x  followed by the statement +y, which is just y

so the same applies for a conditional , if you end with a  && for example the interpreter will continue parsing on the next line

```
x = a &&
b
```

is the same as `x = a && b`

but

```
x = a
&& b
```

is assigns a to x and generates a syntax error for the next line

Answer (score 1):

Your best friend: [CLICK ME](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/)

If you would like to format your conditionals like your first example(I don't know why you would) you can use the `\`format. Try this

```
[2, 3, 4].any? do |x|
  (x > 1 \
  and x < 4)
end
```

Basically just add the slash after each Boolean except your last one!

However standard Ruby convention is to be as short, descriptive, and concise as possible. A similar conditional could be written as so

As johnson said it should be

```
[2, 3, 4].any? { |x| x > 1 && x < 4 }
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Right on with both the link and the first code block. But your second and third code blocks don't adhere to the purpose of `Enumberable#any?` which is just supposed to return a Boolean on the evaluation of your block. So it should be:

`[2, 3, 4].any? { |x| x > 1 && x < 4 }`.

If he wants to put the element or do something with each element, he should use `#each`.

Comment: I didn't take the time to checkout `any?` But I was just mainly trying to emphasize using code blocks instead of `do` for small conditions and using the `&&` because `and` should be used for control flow.