# What's the most official documentation of or way to learn Ruby's syntax?

Tags: ruby, mri

There's https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html, by Yukihiro Matsumoto himself, but given that I can't find mention of `&.` (e.g. `a&.b`) or `&:` (e.g. `m(&:f)`), it doesn't seem very updated. I remember once upon a time there was one person that was trying to document it based on MRI's unit tests, but gave up and abandoned the project because of lack of collaboration from the developers.

Right now, it seems the only way to learn is by stumbling on new syntax by accident on StackOverflow or some open source ruby project.

Comment: You could check `parse.y` in the repo. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663027/ruby-grammar#16629318).

Comment: It is correct that there is no mention of `&:`. There is no such thing.

Comment: @sawa I know, but if it did mention the acceptance of objects as blocks by converting them via `#to_proc` with that syntax (`&` argument prefix), I'd still expect an example in the document to contain the substring `&:`, since the most common use case is with symbol literals.

Comment: @sawa In other words, the goal was to quickly find if the document mentioned that feature, so the best bet was to quickly search for `&:` with Ctrl-F, not because the `&` argument prefix could only be used with symbols, but because it was the most likely substring I could guess to be present in the part I was looking for (probably in an example of usage) to take me directly to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The canonical documentation of Ruby's syntax is maintained along with with language's source code in the `doc/syntax` directory. You can read it on [GitHub](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/v2_5_1/doc/syntax) or e.g. on [ruby-doc.org](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html).

There, you will find [the description](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Receiver) of the `&.` operator:

> You may use `&.` to designate a receiver, then `my_method` is not invoked and the result is `nil` when the receiver is `nil`. In that case, the arguments of `my_method` are not evaluated.

as well as [the logic](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Proc+to+Block+Conversion) to convert a Proc object (or more correctly: an object which can be converted to a Proc) to a block:

> You can convert a proc or lambda to a block argument with the `&` operator:
>
> ```
> argument = proc { |a| puts "#{a.inspect} was yielded" }
>
> my_method(&argument)
> ```

Here, the interesting thing to note is that Symbols respond to [`to_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) which allows Symbols to act like procs (and thus can be converted to a proc and subsequently to a block when used to call a method with e.g. `my_method(&:foo)`.

In general, to learn about Ruby's syntax and approach to programming, you could start with one of several books, e.g. [Programming Ruby 1.9 and 2.0](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0). In general, books tend to take some time (usually a few years) from start to publishing and thus tend to not cover the very latest language additions. However, they can give you a good overview about the language and its core concepts.

There are some additions in newer versions of Ruby which make some things easier, like the `&.` operator added in Ruby 2.3 or things like default frozen strings. While these additions are useful, you will usually stumble upon them when you start to actually programming in Ruby. Here, it might then be useful to follow the [release news](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/) where new features and notable changes are briefly described.

Comment: Unfortunately, the docs only show the explicit proc-to-block conversion and don't even mention the (much more common) implicit conversion via `to_proc`.